# I have this scenario. When I hover to my button, the swf is loaded on stage, but its audio is playing. I just want it to be muted

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

**    >I have this scenario.  When I hover to my button, the swf is loaded on stage, but its audio is playing.  I just want it to be muted.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;

SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

Comment: I also tried it, but the background music in my main stage will be affected too. I want the swf file only when I hover on my button.